# Mongoose Object returns undefined when populating

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm struggling with a little kinda of problem. What I wanna do is populating users in comments.

**User schema:**

```js
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});
```

**Comment schema:**

```js
const commentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  comment:{
    type: String
  },
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
});
```

I had already created user and comment. Everything is fine when I'm trying to find both objects.

**Comment:**

```js
Comment.find({}).exec((err, comments) => {
  console.log(comments);
});
```

**Output:**

```js
[
 {
   _id: 5e62472d5f593f3c642ee1e5,
   comment: 'something',
   user: 5e624522366d8c4150278a64,
   __v: 0
 }
]
```

**User:**

```js
User.find({}).exec((err, users) => {
  console.log(users);
});
```

**Output:**

```js
[
 {
  _id: 5e624522366d8c4150278a64,
  username: "SomeBodY", 
  password: "$2a$10$nm5BJ7zeI1tet3UEzcakf.8xoTgV/Yti5l1EKNg5inxiehevUlGRm"
 }
]
```

The problem is when I'm using `.populate('user')` to `Comment` model it returns the comment as `undefined` in the console. I've tried different methods and even dropping the database but without success.

**Here's the route when this happens**

```js
// Route To Single Project
router.get('/:projectId', (req, res) => {
  const requestedProjectId = req.params.projectId;
  Project.findById({_id: requestedProjectId}).populate('image_file').exec((err, project) => {
    Rating.find({projectId: requestedProjectId}, (err, ratings) => {
      Rating.countDocuments({projectId: requestedProjectId}, (err, count) => {
        Comment.find({projectId: requestedProjectId}).populate('user').exec((err, comments) => {
          console.log(comments)
          if(err) return next(err);
          res.render('project', { ... });
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you add your get route where you try to populate? Also did you create your User model like this? `mongoose.model("User", userSchema)` ?

Comment: Yes, it is like you wrote it.

Comment: Can you test this simple route to see if user is populated? `router.get("/comments", async (req, res) => {
  const comments = await Comment.find().populate("user");
  res.send(comments);
});`

Comment: Yes, user is populated and doesn't return comments as undefined

Comment: Then the problem is not populate. This query returns empty: `Comment.find({projectId: requestedProjectId})`

Comment: Ah, I see. So i need to make the functionbefore that async, if I want the query to return and object. That's solving my problem, thanks a lot.

Comment: It would be good to use async/await to get rid of callback hell. If you want I can post an answer with async/await solution.

Comment: Yeah, sure. Go ahead.

Comment: I would be happy if you can also upvote:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your populate code is true.

The reason to get empty comments is because this `Comment.find({projectId: requestedProjectId})` seems to return empty. So just check your request param.

Also to get rid of callback hell, you can rewrite your route using async/await like this.

```js
router.get("/:projectId", async (req, res) => {
  const requestedProjectId = req.params.projectId;

  try {
    const project = await Project.findById({ _id: requestedProjectId }).populate("image_file");

    if (!project) {
      return res.status(400).send("Project not found, check your projectId");
    }

    const comments = await Comment.find({ projectId: requestedProjectId }).populate("user");
    console.log(comments);

    const ratings = await Rating.find({ projectId: requestedProjectId });

    const count = await Rating.countDocuments({ projectId: requestedProjectId });

    res.render("project", {
      project,
      comments,
      ratings,
      count
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error: ", err);
    res.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
  }
});
```